# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime while converting Datetime

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been trying to convert date time format as below, but keep getting this issue. It works fine for first three of the given Example but for the fourth one, it throws an exception. Not sure why such exception is occurring.

Examples :

- > 02-05-2018 12:07:00
- > 02-05-2018 11:56:00
- > 02-05-2018 11:56:00
- > **02-05-2018 14:12:00** (Problem Occurs on this one)

**C# Code :**

```
if (item.ReceivedDate != null && item.ReceivedDate != "")
{ 
   string[] formats = { "HH:mm:ss MM-dd-yyyy","hh:mm MM/dd/yyyy","dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss","MM/dd/yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy", "dd MMM yy", "dd-MMM-yyyy","dd-MM-yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy", "d-M-yyyy", "d-MMM-yy", "dd-MMM-yy", "d-MMMM-yyyy","M-d-yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M-d-yyyy h:mm tt",
   "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M-d-yyyy h:mm:ss","yyyy-MM-dd","dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm","MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt","MM/dd/yyyy H:mm","MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt",
   "M-d-yyyy hh:mm tt", "M-d-yyyy hh tt","MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss","MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm","MMMM dd","yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss.fffffffK","ddd, dd MMM yyy HH’:’mm’:’ss ‘GMT’",
   "M-d-yyyy h:mm", "M-d-yyyy h:mm","yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss","yyyy MMMM","dddd, dd MMMM yyyy","dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss",
   "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm", "M-dd-yyyy hh:mm",
   "MM-d-yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffffff"};
    string DATE = Convert.ToString(item.ReceivedDate);
    //DATE = DATE.Replace(' ', '-').Replace('/', '-');
    //DATE = DATE.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"));
   string[] NEwDAte = (DATE.ToCharArray()[5] == ' ') ? DATE.Split(' ')[1].Trim().Split('-') : new[] { DATE };
    dr["Receiving Date"] = (DATE.ToCharArray()[5] == ' ') ? (NEwDAte[2] + "-" + NEwDAte[0] + "-" + NEwDAte[1]) : DateTime.ParseExact(DATE, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None ).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    //dr["Receiving Date"] = (DATE.ToCharArray()[5] == ' ') ? (NEwDAte[2] + "-" + NEwDAte[0] + "-" + NEwDAte[1]) : Convert.ToDateTime(item.ReceivedDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
else
{ 
    dr["Receiving Date"] = "";
}
    Finaltable.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
```

Help me resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: OMG, you should really reconsider this whole method, make it simple, stop putting everything on the same line, and please do read the  DateTime.ParseExact documentation, oh and for love of all things beautiful in this world stop abusing null coalescing operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the first three are of type 12-Hours, while the last one is of type 24-Hours so when the system try to convert it,  it see (14) which is not a hour FOR THE CURRENT FORMAT.

The formats you are using are with (hh) which is for 12-Hours. Use (HH) instead, for 24-Hours.

Why are you putting all the formats?  Just use the parsing methods in the DateTime class.

Comment: This what I needed, I just started writing code in c#, guess I have to learn a lot. Thank you Plexis:)

Comment: Glad it  helped! Welcome.. And yes, it is a long journey :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
var d = DateTime.ParseExact("02-05-2018 14:12:00", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(d.ToLongDateString());
```

Check if this helps.

Have a read of **DateTime.ParseExact** Method here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It works for one format but I receive dates comes in different format. so need to use array, when I use iarray this happens.

Comment: How many formats do you want to support? Probably mention them in your question.

Comment: I am not sure what would be thrown at me as input...I want to handle all date time formats..is that possible?

Comment: Umm, think of “02-04-2012”, would you consider this 2nd April 2012 or 4th Feb 2012?

Comment: By default I would consider it as MM-dd-yyyy..? But I get your point that is y=why I put formats in array....not sure if its right way...

Comment: If you must do this, i would suggest creating a list of possible date formats with priorities, and then for given date string loop through the predefined list until you get first proper result. Unfortunately I’m commenting using mobile app and won’t be able to write sample code, but if you haven’t got the answer that satisfies your requirements and are happy to wait, I shall be able to write code in couple of hours.

Comment: Thank you I got the answer and thanks a lot for the support you guys are the best teacher :)